# .zshrc last line parse error near `\n' mac m1

Tags: zsh, apple-m1

As title. It seems that my `.zshrc` last line has some problem. No matter what the last line is, I receive the `.zshrc:119: parse error near` \n'` error. I'm using MAc M1 Max. Have googled some threads but all didn't work.

```js
 Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
DEFAULT_USER="amber-moe"

if brew list | grep coreutils > /dev/null ; then PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" alias ls='ls -F --show-control-chars --color=auto' eval `gdircolors -b $HOME/.dir_colors` fi


# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
#if [ -f '/Users/xiaolang/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/xiaolang/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
 if [ -f '/Users/xiaolang/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/xiaolang/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi
```

This is the last line of my `.zshrc`. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MSDOS endings? Seems like this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the last line; it's that your first `if` statement isn't terminated correctly, so zsh is still looking for the `fi` but finds the EOF instead.

The line

```
if brew list | grep coreutils > /dev/null ; then PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" alias ls='ls -F --show-control-chars --color=auto' eval `gdircolors -b $HOME/.dir_colors` fi
```

Should actually be several lines:

```
if brew list | grep coreutils > /dev/null ; then
  PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
  alias ls='ls -F --show-control-chars --color=auto' eval `gdircolors -b $HOME/.dir_colors`
fi
```

(You can also add semicolons before `alias` and `fi` to achieve the same without breaking the line.)